# Fully Qualified names in Snowflake worksheets

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it considered good practice to always use fully qualified names in Snowflake worksheets ?

Asking because I sometimes see things like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE db.schema.mystage
  url = 'xxxxx'

DESC STAGE db.schema.mystage

ALTER STAGE mystage 
  SET ...
```

where they don't use the fully qualified name for the ALTER STAGE because they say the contect menu for the worksheet is already set to the correct database and schema.

For me this seems inconsistent and potentially prone to error.

So is it good practice to always use fully qualified names in Snowflake worksheets ?

Comment: End goal really.

I mean if the worksheet will be used between environments, uat, prod, dev etc then you don't need to change the entire script in place to apply those changes.

when you specify the qualified names the content is only ever intended to be used in one place.

Like I said, it depends on your goal

Comment: Thank you @patrick_at_snowflake Please can you expand on what you mean by "when you specify the qualified names the content is only ever intended to be used in one place"

Answer (score 4):

Yes it’s good practice to utilize fully qualified name. Particularly useful as you open multiple worksheets and avoid changing dB or schema.

Answer (score 3):

As @patrick_at_snowflake mentions, this really comes down to how the scripts are being used and how you are differentiating environments.  In the case where you are using databases to differentiate dev, uat, prod, etc. then it is useful to not specify the database in all of your object references.  In that case, you may want to qualify schema only, so that running a script in a different environment is as simple as `USE DATABASE prod_db` or `USE DATABASE dev_db` without having to update every qualified object name.

Answer (score 3):

When I am editing/experimenting/testing in the worksheet I use fully qualified names, so I can share SQL with team members and have it "just work" for them, no matter what there worksheet is pointing at.

When we run our code in prod, we replaced the database/schema names with tokens that are replaced depending on the deployment target. The nice thing about this is when you look at execution history you get fully qualified names, so can re-run queries without a lot of fiddling.

But I also would not use full names if I was writing a bug report/repro, as it db/schema is not needed, and a working example should have all the related data, imo.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is always good practice to have fully qualified object names in your script, not just in the worksheet, but in general, including your UDFs and SPs.

This can help to avoid potential errors if you forget to switch between schemas or databases and data get updated into the wrong target, or reading from the wrong source.

It can help to save lots of your debugging time down the track.